# Не выходит из цикла при чтении из файла

Tags: c++, строки, struct

Во время считывания из файла функция не выходит из цикла,

Структура:

```
struct Example
{
    string Name;
    string Adder;
    int newList;
    int newListAdd;
};
```

Функция для чтения:

```
Example *readFile(ifstream &arg) {
    arg.open("other.txt", ios_base::in);
    Example *arg2 = new Example[2];

    int i = 0;
    if (arg.is_open()) {
        while (!arg.eof()) {
            getline(arg, (arg2[i]).Name);
            getline(arg, (arg2[i]).Adder);
            arg  >> (arg2[i]).newList >> (arg2[i]).newListAdd;
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Error";
    }

    arg.close();
    return arg2;
}
```

Как пример файла:

```
gigehi
ihuiguh iuhi
222
111
girehgirh 
hjrto jojhortj
333
222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный цикл

```
    while (!arg.eof()) {
        getline(arg, (arg2[i]).Name);
        getline(arg, (arg2[i]).Adder);
        arg  >> (arg2[i]).newList >> (arg2[i]).newListAdd;
        i++;
    }
```

логически не верный.

Вы должны проверять, что цикл не будет продолжаться более двух раз, так как вы определили массив только из двух элементов, который вы собираетесь заполнить данными из файла

```
Example *arg2 = new Example[2];
                           ^^^^
```

Кроме того имеет место попытка чтения пустого файла, так как после того, как будет прочитана последняя запись файла, состояние конца файла еще не наступит, пока не будет предпринята попытка прочитать несуществующую запись после последней записи файла. А это значит, что в поля массива будут занесен неверные данные.

Что касается зацикливания, то после данного предложения с оператором `operator >>`

```
arg  >> (arg2[i]).newList >> (arg2[i]).newListAdd;
```

в буфере ввода сохраняется символ новой строки `'\n'`, а функция `std::getline` Считывает строку до этого символа. В результате после первой итерации цикла в данном предложении

```
getline(arg, (arg2[i]).Name);
```

считывается пустая строка из-за оставшегося в буфере ввода символа новой строки от предыдущей итерации цикла.
Следующее предложение

```
getline(arg, (arg2[i]).Adder);
```

считывает запись файла `girehgirh` , а затем предложение

```
arg  >> (arg2[i]).newList >> (arg2[i]).newListAdd;
```

пытается занести запись файла `hjrto jojhortj` в целые числа. Возникает ошибка ввода-вывод, которая так и сохраняется, а потому ничего далее из файла не считывается.

Вам надо либо все строки вводить с помощью функции `std::getline`, а затем строки преобразовывать в целые числа для целочисленных полей структуры. Либо после предложения

```
arg  >> (arg2[i]).newList >> (arg2[i]).newListAdd;
```

удалять оставшийся в буфере символ новой строки `'\n'`. Это можно сделать следующим образом

```
#include <limits>

//...

arg  >> (arg2[i]).newList >> (arg2[i]).newListAdd;
arg.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()), '\n' );
```